# JedisPooled is unable to read data from the AWS Elastic Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, jedis, amazon-elasticache

We are trying to connect to AWS Elastic Redis Cluster using following code:

```
    public class RedisConnection {
    private JedisPooled jedisPooled;

    public RedisConnection(final RedisConfiguration configuration) {
        this.jedisPooled = new JedisPooled(new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>(), configuration.redisHostname(),
                                           configuration.redisPort(),
                                           2000,
                                           configuration.redisPassword());
    }

    public JedisPooled getJedisPooled() {
        return this.jedisPooled;
    }
}
```

I am using the above class to read the data from redis cluster:

```
    public class RedisCacheService implements CacheService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisCacheService.class);
    private final RedisConnection redisConnection;

    public RedisCacheService(final RedisConnection redisConnection) {
        this.redisConnection = redisConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(final String key) {
        LOG.debug("start to find cache with {}" , key);
        final Optional<String> result = Optional.ofNullable(redisConnection.getJedisPooled().get(key));
        return result.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Getting Read timed out error:

```
    2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:208)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:46)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:126)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:316)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:243)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.auth(Connection.java:372)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.initializeFromClientConfig(Connection.java:345)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:53)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.ConnectionFactory.makeObject(ConnectionFactory.java:71)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:571)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:298)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:223)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:34)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:28)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:7)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.providers.PooledConnectionProvider.getConnection(PooledConnectionProvider.java:54)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.executors.DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(DefaultCommandExecutor.java:23)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis.executeCommand(UnifiedJedis.java:148)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis.get(UnifiedJedis.java:570)

2022-09-16T13:13:19.883+02:00   at com.govipul.learning.redis.impl.RedisCacheService.getValue(RedisCacheService.java:36)
```

The beauty is when i try to run the code from my local using tunnel to AWS cluster it works, but when i run the code from the EC2 instance it is failing.
so it will be helpful if anyone can help on how can i run my code in EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to SSL, i have enabled the SSL on the AWS Elastic redis side and hence the flag has to be enabled when creating the connection.
The **JedisPooled** have a constructor with last parameter as Boolean SSL flag with value true/false.

```
this.jedisPooled = new JedisPooled(new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>(), 
                                           configuration.redisHostname(),
                                           configuration.redisPort(),
                                           2000,
                                           configuration.redisPassword(),
                                           true);
```